# Wildfly loadbalancer log

Tags: java, wildfly, load-balancing, undertow, wildfly-11

I have a setup which has one load balancer(wildly-11 in load balancer profile) at front and two server nodes(wildly-11) at the back.Now i need load balancer log which can give details about request transferred to which node.Can anyone explain how we can make those log appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the DEBUG log level for *io.undertow.server.handlers.proxy* package in the WildFly config . Example from *standalone/configuration/standalone-load-balancer.xml*:

```xml
<logger category="io.undertow.server.handlers.proxy">
   <level name="DEBUG"/>
</logger>
```

After that, you will see the information about requests' proxying in the log. 
Example:

```
13:05:06,274 DEBUG [io.undertow.server.handlers.proxy] (default I/O-13) Sending request ClientRequest{path='/xxx-app', method=GET, protocol=HTTP/1.1} to target /127.0.0.1:8009 for exchange HttpServerExchange{ GET /xxx-app request {Accept=[text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8], Accept-Language=[en-US,en;q=0.5], Cache-Control=[max-age=0], Accept-Encoding=[gzip, deflate], User-Agent=[...], Connection=[keep-alive], Cookie=[JSESSIONID=B9mIIaGz2QYcPBbODJxvY04wjjRnfSz0r2iYh7VQ.node6], Upgrade-Insecure-Requests=[1], Host=[localhost:8080]} response {}}
13:05:06,274 DEBUG [io.undertow.server.handlers.proxy] (default I/O-13) Sent request ClientRequest{path='/xxx-app', method=GET, protocol=HTTP/1.1} to target 127.0.0.1 for exchange HttpServerExchange{ GET /xxx-app request {Accept=[text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8], Accept-Language=[en-US,en;q=0.5], Cache-Control=[max-age=0], Accept-Encoding=[gzip, deflate], User-Agent=[...], Connection=[keep-alive], Cookie=[JSESSIONID=B9mIIaGz2QYcPBbODJxvY04wjjRnfSz0r2iYh7VQ.node6], Upgrade-Insecure-Requests=[1], Host=[localhost:8080]} response {}}
13:05:06,452 DEBUG [io.undertow.server.handlers.proxy] (default I/O-13) Received response ClientResponse{responseHeaders={X-Powered-By=[JSF/1.2], Content-Type=[text/html;charset=UTF-8], Date=[Wed, 13 Nov 2019 10:05:06 GMT]}, responseCode=200, status='OK', protocol=HTTP/1.1} for request ClientRequest{path='/xxx-app', method=GET, protocol=HTTP/1.1} for exchange HttpServerExchange{ GET /xxx-app request {Accept=[text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8], Accept-Language=[en-US,en;q=0.5], Cache-Control=[max-age=0], Accept-Encoding=[gzip, deflate], User-Agent=[...], Connection=[keep-alive], Cookie=[JSESSIONID=B9mIIaGz2QYcPBbODJxvY04wjjRnfSz0r2iYh7VQ.node6], Upgrade-Insecure-Requests=[1], Host=[localhost:8080]} response {}}
```